# Get UserName value from Login Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to obtain the value of the UserName field in an ASP.net login control. here is my .net:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD" BorderPadding="4"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
                ForeColor="#333333" TextLayout="TextOnTop" DestinationPageUrl="~/Receipt.aspx" 
                UserNameLabelText="User Name (From: xxxxx.com):" Height="105px" PasswordRecoveryText="Forgot User Name or Password?" PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/GetPassword.aspx">
            <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" />
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            </asp:Login>
```

here is my vb that i'm storing the value in a txt file - no error when run but no value is entered either.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim xUserName As String = User.Identity.Name()
    'UpdateLastLoginDate(xUserName)
End Sub

Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim username As String = Request.Form("UserName")
    Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath("~") + "debug.txt"

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(filepath)
        writer.WriteLine(username)
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`UserName Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) of `ASP.NET` login control like

```
Dim username As String = Login1.UserName;
```

Comment: still nothing? replaced `Dim username As String = Request.Form("UserName")` with `Dim username As String = Login1.UserName`

Comment: @BarclayVision, are you sure you entered some text in the username textbox?

Comment: yes. I'm not sure where the `LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` is origionaled from - is this event getting fired?

Comment: @BarclayVision, Well in your posted code I don't see that event at all. Since it's user control that to a built in one ... that event you can't register. Rather the event should be `OnAuthenticate`. Check in your code.

Comment: im trying to capture the username entry of non-authenticated users, so any entry is recorded. is there another way to do this?

Comment: the page source button is: `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton" value="Log In" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton" style="color:#990000;background-color:White;border-color:#CC9966;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.8em;" />`

Comment: @BarclayVision, that's what I said. Do this processing on `OnAuthenticate` event rather.

Comment: sorry im very new to this, can you provide an example?

Comment: @BarclayVision, see the linked MSDN document in answer. Read the answer carefully. Search in google lots of sample code is present. no point in duplicating those again here.

Comment: Hey one last question? when i add `<asp:Login ID="Login1" OnAuthenticate="MySub" runat="server"` the UserName is written to the text file but the user is not authenticated and fails the login?

Answer (score 0):

moved to new question asked in a more precise way:
[Call a function from the Login Control in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553775/call-a-function-from-the-login-control-in-vb-net)

working result is:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(Login1)
End Sub

Private Sub WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(parent As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, Button).Click, AddressOf MyFunction
        ElseIf ctrl.HasControls() Then
            WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MyFunction(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim username As String = Login1.UserName
    Dim currentDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)
    Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath("~") + "\debug.txt"

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filepath)
        writer.WriteLine(username)
        writer.WriteLine(currentDateTime)
        writer.WriteLine("")
    End Using
End Sub
```