# Call a function from the Login Control in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to call a function in code behind but not working - one suggestion was to use the `OnAuthenticate` instead of the `OnClick` however this requires a rewrite of the entire authentication process.

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnClick="MyButton"  DestinationPageUrl="~/Receipt.aspx" 
   UserNameLabelText="User Name (From: mysite.com):" 
   PasswordRecoveryText="Forgot User Name or Password?" 
   PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/GetPassword.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```

vb code:

```
Protected Sub MyButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim username As String = Login1.UserName
    Dim currentDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)
    Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath("~") + "\debug.txt"

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filepath)
        writer.WriteLine(username)
        writer.WriteLine(currentDateTime)
        writer.WriteLine("")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Revised Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim xUserName As String = User.Identity.Name()
    'UpdateLastLoginDate(xUserName)
End Sub

Protected Sub MyButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim username As String = Login1.UserName
    Dim pw As String = Login1.Password
    Dim currentDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)
    Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath("~") + "\debug.txt"

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filepath)
        writer.WriteLine(username)
        writer.WriteLine(pw)
        writer.WriteLine(currentDateTime)
        writer.WriteLine("REMOTE_ADDR: " + Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))
        writer.WriteLine("USER_AGENT: " + Request.Servervariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
        writer.WriteLine("LOCAL_ADDR: " + Request.Servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR"))
        writer.WriteLine("LOGON_USER: " + Request.Servervariables("LOGON_USER"))
        'writer.WriteLine(Request.Servervariables("ALL_HTTP"))
        writer.WriteLine("")
    End Using
End Sub 

Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(Login1)
End Sub

Private Sub WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(parent As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, Button).Click, Function() (MyFunction())
        ElseIf ctrl.HasControls() Then
            WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function MyFunction() As String
    Response.Write("Function Called")
    Return Nothing
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: When you say "not working", what's happening? Can you not step in to the code?

Comment: its runs without errors but never fires the function. seems the control has no button event and the onClick is not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(Login1)
End Sub

Private Sub WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(parent As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, Button).Click, AddressOf MyFunction
        ElseIf ctrl.HasControls() Then
            WireLoginControlButtonClickEvent(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MyFunction(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Write("Function Called")
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i'm using vb.net

Comment: error: "expression expected" on `AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, Button).Click, Function() (MyFunction())`

Comment: Did you create your own Login control? Why does your code look like this: 
Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page?

Comment: i don't understand your question - its a web page, with standard login control - removed the onClick but its the same as the original html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89536/discussion-between-thewisegod-and-barclayvision).